# Creating a dynamic table for dynamic data with a for loop html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to add dynamic data generated in a for loop into a table with javascript. Heres my code

```
<script>

var setA = [];
var setB = [];
var newline = "<br>";
var space = "  ";


for(var i = 1; i < 13; i++){
    setA.push("<i+space);

}

document.write(setA+newline);

for(var i = 1; i < 13; i++){ 
setB.push(i*i+space);

}   

document.write(setB);

</script>
```

this is the result:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1 ,4 ,9 ,16 ,25 ,36 ,49 ,64 ,81 ,100 ,121 ,144

the result im looking for is to have these numbers contained inside a table, ive looked at examples online but i dont know how i would apply it to this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the table HTML tag?

```
var code = "<table><tr>";
for (var i=0; i<13; i++) {
    code += `<th>${i}</th>`;
}
code += "</tr><tr>";
for (var i=0; i<13; i++) {
    code += `<th>${i*i}</th>`;
}
code += "</tr></table>";

document.write(code);
```

Comment: yes, but as i said in my question i didn't know how i was supposed to apply those tags within this context, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code snippet, it should solve your problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this.json = {
    "Students": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hometown": "London",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "8",
        "name": "Lee",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "hometown": "NY",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "9",
        "name": "Shaldon",
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "hometown": "Paris",
        "gender": "Female",
        "GPA": "7",
        "name": "Julie",
      }
    ]
  };
  
  this.renderTable = function(Students) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>ID</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].id + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>HomeTown</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].hometown + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>Gender</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].gender + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>GPA</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].GPA + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>NAME</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<hr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
  }

  this.renderTable(this.json.Students);

  console.log(this.json.Students);
  //code for filtering//
  this.Filter = function() {
    var search = document.getElementById('search');
    var category = document.getElementById('category');
    var filteredObj = this.json.Students;
    filteredObj = $.map(this.json.Students, function(val, key) {
      if (search.value === val[category.value]) return val;
    });
    filteredObj.length>0 ? this.renderTable(filteredObj) : this.renderTable(this.json.Students);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="search" type="search">
<select id = "category">
<option value = "select">select</option>
   <option value = "id">ID</option>
   <option value = "hometown">HomeTown</option>
   <option value = "gender">Gender</option>
   <option value = "GPA">GPA</option>
   <option value = "name">NAME</option>
  </select>
<button onclick="Filter()">Filter</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```